# How to get frame image for every frame in video stream?

Tags: android, video, streaming, video-streaming

I'm going to use [ExoPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) to play video stream over the network which is said to be new hackable embeddable android player. How can i get every frame image using it's API? Can i get frames without displaying it in SurfaceView as i'm going to use frames images in OpenGL SurfaceView?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing